# Is there a race condition when using cloud functions inside a UIAlertController action?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, uialertcontroller

I using a native UIAlertController action in my app to allow a user to report an individual post, and I'm using Firebase to create a data structure for these reports. However, for whatever reason, the cloud function is not being executed, and I'm wondering whether this is due to some race condition that's related to using the UIAlertController. I'm able to execute a print statement inside the handler, so there's nothing wrong with the alert action per se.

Below is my code.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        // Report Post
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Report", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            
            print("you've pressed report")
            
            guard let postId = self.post?.postId else { return }
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            let creationDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    
            let values = ["creationDate": creationDate,
                          "uid": uid] as [String : Any]
    
            REPORT_REF.child(postId).childByAutoId().updateChildValues(values)

        }))
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it looks like you're updating a Firestore reference? Which line of code should be calling the cloud function?

Comment: what do you mean by a race condition here ?

Comment: @thecoolwinter the line that starts with "REPORT_REF..."

Comment: Different topic : be careful of memory leak when using self in closure without using capture list ```[weak self] in```.

About your question : you print before the guards does it still print if you move the instruction after the guards?

Comment: you should validate this line if it passes from your guard let coditions
             `guard let postId = self.post?.postId else { return }`
            `guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }` --- move the print log at the bottom after every execution so you can be sure if it's reaching the last function

Comment: @Lapieuvre Good catch. Not sure why it's returning, given that there is indeed a post as well as a current user.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I was able to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can use breakpoint and look at the value you are testing in the guard to see what they are and which one of them is returning. Also since the closure are executed asynchronously it's possible the values you are testing are dereferenced or changed when the user click the button.